# How does INRIX traffic monitoring work?

Tags: java

How does INRIX traffic monitoring work?

How would I develop a Java application that uses Inrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thor is right.  The place to go is the [INRIX DevZone](http://www.inrix.com/devzone.asp).  I'm a developer on the mobile team at INRIX and recognize that gaining access to our APIs isn't as easy as it could be.  We're looking at how we can improve that experience and make them available in a more friction-free manner.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

INRIX is a company providing traffic information, I assume that they don't publish their internal algorithms to tell everybody how their system works.

If you want to develop an application I strongly suggest that you sign up to the [INRIX DevZone](http://www.inrix.com/devzone.asp).